# ComboBox ItemSource in DataGrid Not Correctly Working

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm trying to put one ComboBox into the DataGrid in one Row, I need to `load Items` for Editing and
`Read item Data and Show as Name` Correctly
i got One Table as `Device`

```
 public class Device:BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PlaceId { get; set; }
        public short RoomNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`PlaceId` is a **foreign key** with this Properties:

```
 public class Place:BaseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int PlaceId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long? PhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string Manager { get; set; }
}
```

this is my problem, not correctly Working...
[image]

how can I load Places in this combo box? and how can I edit that?
here is my codes:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="نام مجموعه">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Place.Name}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Place.Name}" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

C# Behind Cod is:

```
public UcDevice()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this._device;
    GetDevices();

}
public void GetDevices()
{
    var uCollection = new ObservableCollection<Device>();
    foreach (var v in _context.Devices) uCollection.Add(v);
    DgDevice.ItemsSource = uCollection;
}
```

Comment: Not sure which items you are intending to show in the ComboBox, but binding its ItemsSource to the string `Place.Name` will not work. The ComboBox interprets the source string as an `IEnumerable<char>`, and hence shows single character items.

Comment: in Class Places , i need to load all Places as `places.Name` only into that ComboBox